# Connect IBM informix database in Python

Tags: python, informix

I am trying to connect an Informix database in python using the ibm_db library, the implemented code is the following:

```
import ibm_db
conn_str = "DATABASE=xxxx;HOSTNAME=xxx.xx.xx.xx;PORT=xxxx;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=xxxxxx;PWD=xxxxx.;"
conn = ibm_db.connect(conn_str, "xxxx", "xxxx")
```

When applying this code, it does not connect and throws the following error:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-03b7e2ae7a5b> in <module>
       1 import ibm_db
       2 conn_str = "DATABASE=xxxx;HOSTNAME=xxx.xx.xx.xx;PORT=xxxx;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=xxxx;PWD=xxxxxx;"
 ----> 3 conn = ibm_db.connect(conn_str, "xxxx", "xxxxx")
  Exception: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected. Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP".  Communication API being used: "SOCKETS".  Location where the error was detected: "xxx.xx.xx.xx".  Communication function detecting the error: "recv".  Protocol specific error code(s): "*", "*", "0".  SQLSTATE=08001  SQLCODE=-30081
```

What could be happening?

Comment: This should indicate that the connection was reset by a peer, however, the causes may differ - see the [possible causes in the documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=errors-sql30081n-tcpip-communication).
Are you sure that the hostname & port you are using are correct? Don't you have a firewall or other security tools in place, that might be closing the connection?

Comment: The text of the error message shows that the IBM Db2 driver is being used. Is the corresponding port on the Informix server configured for the DRDA protocol as opposed to the usual Informix SQLI protocol? For example, in the server's sqlhosts file the connection type would be drsoctcp instead of onsoctcp.